# Creating a unique, auto assigned variable with Microsofts Extensible Storage Engine

Tags: c++, database, extensible-storage-engine

I'm using Extensible Storage Engine and want a unique column (32bits wide).  I need the values in this column to be auto assigned by the database

I'm hoping to find something like JET_bitIndexUnique that I can mask in?

if there isnt such a mask whats the proper way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see: [Version, Auto-Increment and Escrow Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964814(EXCHG.10).aspx)

> Auto increment columns are automatically
>   incremented by ESE when a new record
>   is inserted into the table. The value
>   contained in the auto-increment column
>   is unique for every record in the
>   table and is not guaranteed to be
>   continuous. These values are not
>   recycled, but can be reused in certain
>   cases. Only columns of type
>   JET_coltypLong (Long) and JET_coltypLongLong
>   (Currency) may be auto increment columns.

Wiki: [Extensible Storage Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine)